# Identity element of the operation $x*y = \min\{x+1, y+1\}$ on $\mathbb R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The following is an operation $*$ on $\mathbb R$.

$$x*y= \min\{x+1, y+1\}$$

Explain whether or not $\mathbb R$ has an identity element with respect to $*$.

This question also had two other parts, asking to explain whether it is commutative and associative. I said that it is commutative but not associative.

As for the identity element, I am confused because $\mathbb R$ goes to $-\infty$ so won't we always be able to find an element that is smaller than $x+1$?

I feel like there cannot be a neutral element because the operation $*$ is defined on $\mathbb R$ and I feel like you will always be able to find a smaller element than $x+1$.

Plus, the neutral element has to be unique so how could this operation have a unique neutral element?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What is $x*x{}$?

Comment: But that isn't unique for the operation?

Comment: $x*y = \min(x, y) + 1$.

Comment: @amWhy I'm not sure I understand your answer

Comment: It's true, though.

Comment: But that's not the operation? x*y = min{x+1, y+1}

Comment: Oh nevermind, I get it!

Comment: It is equivalent to you operation, JxxYsde3.  I simply thought looking at what the operation is actually doing might be helpful.

Comment: But even in that scenario, isn't the neutral element still not unique?

Comment: @JxxYsde3 : In proper MathJax and LaTeX usage, the whole expression $$ x*y= \min\{x+1, y+1\} $$ should be between only one pair of dollar signs or double dollar signs. See that and my other edits to the question.

Comment: The operation isn't interesting, I bet it isn't even associative. And there isn't a neutral element, naturally, exactly for the reason you doubt it: it would mean $x*e=x$ for all $x$, but if $x<e$, you have $x*e=x+1\neq x$.

Comment: The neutral element, say $e \in \mathbb R$ must be such that $e*x = x$, that is $\min(e, x) + 1 = x$, for all $x \in \mathbb R$.  But lets just pick $x_1 \in \mathbb R$.  $\min(e, x_1) + 1 = x_1 \iff e = x_1 - 1$.  But we see quickly, this identity depends on (is unique for) each $x \in \mathbb R$.  So no, there does not exist a unique neutral (identity) element $e$ in $\mathbb R$ such that for all $x \in \mathbb R, $e*x = x*e = x$

Answer (score -1):

The operation $x*y = \min(x+1, y+1)$, for $x, y \in \mathbb R$, is equivalent to the following:

$$x*y = \min(x, y) + 1$$

The neutral element, say $e \in \mathbb R$ must be such that $e*x = x*e = x$, that is $\min(e, x) + 1 = \min(x, e) +1 = x$, for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

But let's just pick a specific $x_1 \in \mathbb R$ to text.  $\min(e, x_1) + 1 = \min(x_1, e) = x_1 \iff e = x_1 - 1$.

Let's try another distinct element, $x_2 \neq x_1$ in $\mathbb R$.  We need $e' \in \mathbb R$ such that $e'*x_2 = x_2*e' = x_2 \iff e'= x_2 - 1$.

But we see that $e'\neq e$, because $e = x_1 -1$, and $e'= x_2 - 1$, and since $x_1\neq x_2$, we know that $e' \neq e$.

So  we see quickly, that there is a different "neutral element" dependent on and defined for, each distinct element $x\in \mathbb R$.

So no, there does not exist a unique neutral (identity) element $e$ in $\mathbb R$ such that ***for all*** $x \in \mathbb R$, $e*x = x*e = x$.

Comment: I'm surprised by this terminology: if a neutral element exists, it _is_ unique. If we had two neutral elements, $e$ and $e'$, we'd have $e=e*e'=e'$ by definition.

Comment: My point being, @Professor, I am showing that using the property of a neutral element e with respect to a set (real numbers) given the operation $*$, that property being that there exists one element, $e$ unique in that for all $x \in \mathbb e* x = x*e = x$ fails, because for each specific $x \in \mathbb R$ the satisfying "e" applies is specific and valid for that specific $x$; i.e., there is no "universal, unique identity $e\in \mathbb R$" that serves as an identity for each and every  $x \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Kind of like:  we have that $$\forall x \in \mathbb R, \exists! e\in \mathbb R (e*x = x*e = x)$$ But we also have that $$\not \exists e! \in \mathbb R, \forall x \in \mathbb R(e*x= x*e = x)$$  And because of the latter statement, no such neutral (identity) element e exists for the operation $*$, on the Real numbers.

Comment: Iron logic, I'd say. =D.